# Enable/disable submesh set with SetTriangles(triangles, submesh)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an imported model which I alter with SetTriangles. Basically I cut the model up in multiple smaller pieces so one can be rendered and others can not. The cutting happens at runtime and several submeshes can end up sharing the same Material.

This is working fine, however I have no idea how to selectively render submeshes I've created. This is perfectly possible with OpenGL and DirectX (indexbuffers), and Unity's Graphics.DrawMesh seems to have a parameter for it, but I can't find anything on how to do this in Unity.

As a note; the created submeshes do not show in the Unity Editor tree.

**Edit**

The submeshes cannot be destroyed and created in the process; that's important as that will most likely lead to slow performance.

**Edit**

I figure I could just call Graphics.DrawMesh and disable the Renderer. Is this the best/only way?

Comment: submeshes sort of don't exist really and don't mean much in Unity.  they're just separate objects.  **"turn them on and off" simply using .enable on the renderer - or for that matter simply turn the whole game object off (SetActive(false)).** no big deal.  if you're coming from another field where there's talk of submeshes, pretty much just forget that in Unity :)  Graphics.DrawMesh sort of has nothing to do with anything, I'd forget it

Comment: you can and should google 100s of discussions on this, http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/709513/view.html http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/469827/view.html http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/312579/view.html really you should pretty much just forget about submeshes in unity (maybe any game engine). they are just separate "things" .. deal with them that way. it's child's play

Comment: may i suggest, **state what you are actually trying to do** (ie "you're making a game with a dog" or "you're making minecraft" or whatever). honestly, it saves a lot of time

Comment: How does drawmesh not work? It draws the submesh, as it says in the description. Going into detail of what I'm trying to do will add little, but: I'm looking to occlude parts of the model so rendering happens as fast as possible.think a model standing against the wall. I have multiple submeshes for multiple positions each one.

Comment: Hmm, just purely FWIW, did you know Unity has superb occlusion culling completely built-in?  For example, if you're making, a good example might be a typical totally dynamic track of some sort (sounds somewhat like what you're doing) you very simply (quite incredibly really) just ensure it is split in to pieces. By "split into pieces" I mean nothing more than at the GameObject metaphor level.  "This is not OpenGL, it's just a game engine". After doing that, the occlusion culling does an astounding job, even if you write occlusion culling for a living. The problem may be tremendously...

Comment: ..simpler than you're thinking.  Regarding "DrawMesh" or whatever it's called, you may want `DrawMeshNow`.  But it's just **not how Unity works**.  it would be like worrying about the ascii representation of text ---- when you're using a word processor to write your diary. You know? You can easily google the few discussions on DrawMesh eg http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/395091/how-do-we-get-just-one-drawcall-with-drawmesh.html http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1102797/how-to-do-multiple-graphicsdrawmesh-calls-in-a-c-s.html

Comment: I agree with @JoeBlow, it's not how unity works. I guess you are saving your submeshes in their own separate **Mesh** variables right? With that given what I would do is have a game object with **MeshFilter** and **MeshRenderer** components attached to it and change **mesh** property in **MeshFilter** as I need. I'd assign my submeshes to it at runtime.

Comment: You may as well try to fiddle with Camera's **Culling Mask** property. So if you have 3 GameObjects described above, rendering 3 different meshes, you could put them in different layers. Then by changing camera's **Culling Mask** you could decide which ones would get rendered. Or you could change **Layer** of the GameObjects.

Comment: Come on.. You must somehow be able to use multiple index buffers with the same vertexbuffer.

Comment: Hi RobotRock.  It can be tricky moving from being "an openGL programmer" to "a game engine programmer". You're at the "implementation details" level in a game engine.  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.SetIndices.html  Consider including s screenshot of what you're actually up to. I may misunderstand what you're trying to do.  If you wish to work at a lower level, a game engine is not for you - enjoy openGL!  Cheers for now

Comment: Since game engines are built on OpenGL and DirectX, I expect them to be able to do at least the basic things OpenGL and DirectX can do. However I figured out how Graphics.DrawMesh is supposed to be used and it works like expected.

Comment: Hi RobotRock. You thought wrong!  :)  Unity is just for mucking about with PhysX etc.  lower level support is non-existent, as you have found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with Graphics.DrawMesh which allows to render a submesh.

A note; it's very difficult and costly to apply animations with Graphics.DrawMesh.